# Как вернуть значение без маски из компонента vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть компонент `text-field` ранее он служил как просто текстовое поле что пишешь то и получаешь, но появилась необходимость добавить в props маску. Использую [данную](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask). Сам компонент условно выглядит следующим образом

В итоге я получаю в родительском компоненте в `price` строковое значение с маской конкретно в этом случае `$ 1,100.00`. Если в `$emit` отдавать преобразованное значение без лишних символов то последующем редактировании происходит постоянно непонятные ситуации (то каретка улетает, то дробная часть залетает в целую сразу).

```js
Vue.component('text-field', {
  props: {
    value: String,
    name: String,
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text'
    },
    mask: Object
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        return this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Inputmask({ 
      placeholder: '',
      ...this.mask,
    }).mask(this.$refs[this.name]);
  },
  template: `
  <input
    :type="type"
    :name="name"
    :ref="name"
    v-model="model">`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      price: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/inputmask/dependencyLibs/inputmask.dependencyLib.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/inputmask/inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/inputmask/4.0.9/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ price }}</div>
  <text-field
    :name="'price'"
    :mask="{alias: 'currency', rightAlign: false, max: 100}"
    v-model="price"/>
</div>
```

Собственно вопрос можно как то в компоненте уже отдавать преобразованное значение? или каждый раз в родительском компоненте нужно писать какой то обработчик (а ведь поле не одно может быть и с разной маской)

p.s. заметил еще баг что если одним из параметров выбрать максимум или минимум то после потери фокуса значение в поле изменится, но оно не узменится в родительском компоненте (на событие blur поставить так же обработчик?)

Comment: приведите воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Дмытрык добавил